# undefined method `add_record_to_target_with_callbacks for Array` - when upgrade to Ruby 2.1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I've the following models :

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :children, :dependent => :destory
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :children, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

When assigning :

```
per.children_attributes = { '0' => {'name' => 'ben' } }
```

i receive the following exception: 
`undefined method add_record_to_target_with_callbacks for Array`

The stacktrace :

`/home/nitzany/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-3.0.20/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:159:in send
/home/nitzany/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-3.0.20/lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb:376:in 'block in assign_nested_attributes_for_collections_association
/home/nitzany/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-3.0.20/lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb:367:in 'each'
/home/nitzany/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-3.0.20/lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb:367: in 'assign_nested_attributes_for_collection_association"
/home/nitzany/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activerecord-3.0.20/lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb:254:in children_attributers=`

- When downgrade to ruby 1.9.2 problems resolved
- When catching the exception and running the same line of code again, problem resolved

Any help?

Comment: I suggest you to do not use ActiveRecord 3.0.2 with Ruby 2.1.0; I don't think Rails 3.0.2 was tested to work with Ruby 2

Comment: I edited my question. We use Rails 3.0.20, not 3.0.2. Is it still not recommended? if not, from which Rails version is it Ok to use Ruby 2, i couldn't find any documentation about it.

Comment: Check [this](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2013/2/24/maintenance-policy-for-ruby-on-rails/): as you can see, Rails bugs are fixed only on the latest release, that at the moment is 4.1. Since Ruby 2 was released after 4.0 release, Rails 3.0 was not supported at the time, and so Ruby 2 is not guaranteed to work on Rails 3.0. Rails 3.2 works fine with Ruby >= 2